# Problem driving solenoids with an IRF540 power MOSFET

Tags: mosfet, switching, solenoid

[image]I am using an IRF540PBF power MOSFET to drive a solenoid with 24VDC which works beautifully. When I try to drive a stronger solenoid the MOSFET gets stuck in the on position until I power the system off. Upon powering the system back on the MOSFET works fine so there does not seem to be any damage to it.

I don't have exact specs for the solenoids but here are the various duty cycles and resistances:

- 25% ED (~10R)
- 15% ED (~6R)
- 10% ED (~4R)
- 5% ED (~3R)

The 25% ED version works without a problem, <=15% ED and the MOSFET gets stuck in the on position after 2 - 3 activations.

Activation times are around 30ms. I am not using PWM since I do not need to hold the solenoid in place and want maximum power during activation.

There are two Schottky diodes in place, a 1N4007 directly across the solenoid terminals and a SK510A-LTP across my driver board's output.

Any suggestions on how I can resolve this issue?

Edit: schematic added

Comment: What exactly are you driving the gate with?

Comment: The 1N4007 is not a Schottky diode.

Comment: I am using an ESP32 to control the signal going into an LTV-817S-TA1 optocoupler. Pin 4 is connected directly to 24V and pin 3 outputs to a voltage divider (4.7K / 100K), the divided output goes into the gate.

Comment: Please measure gate-source voltage on MOSFET that should be off but isn't. My guess is leakage through the opto + high value pull down resistor causes Vgs to be not exactly zero but some low voltage, and your hot FET drops its threshold voltage enough to conduct at that Vgs. (threshold voltage has negative tempco, so the hotter it is the lower the threshold)

Comment: 100k is a lot for a MOSFET's gate. When your IC pulls the gate low, it has to do so by draining the charge through the 4k7 resistor. This is a poor design for a gate driver. You can try to improve the design by adding a gate driver that puts 12 V and 0 V to the gate via a low-impedance path.

Comment: A couple of thoughts: Could you add a circuit diagram?  That's much better than us visualising from your comments.  What does "ED" stand for in the solenoid specs?

Comment: Is ESP32 rated for LTV-817S-TA1 20 mA input ...

Comment: ED is the duty cycle of a solenoid, so a 100% ED means the solenoid can be left on, anything lower and you have to let it cool down between activations because it builds up too much heat.

Comment: I didn't have enough GPIO pins so there's a MCP23008 I2C port expander between the ESP32 and the LTV-817S-TA1, the MCP23008 can output 25mA so that should be OK.

Comment: Is the MCP23008 sharing ground with the switch? An opto isn't much value if isolation isn't required; a pair of transistors can do the level shifting with much less sacrifice to speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for everybody's input! I was still experiencing the same issue after implementing *Spehro Pefhany* follower circuit so I went ahead and started monitoring the gate with an oscilloscope which revealed that the MOSFET wasn't the culprit after all. Some further testing showed that the stronger solenoid leads to massive ground fluctuations (1.6V!) on the power supply board which crashes the ESP and leads to the output staying on instead of disengaging after 30ms like I programmed. Looks like there's some work to be done on the power supply...

Answer (score 8):

You're almost certainly violating the SOA (Safe Operating Area) of the MOSFET with that drive circuit when it turns off glacially slowly as the very substantial gate charge bleeds off through the 100kΩ resistor.

Add a PNP/NPN emitter follower circuit to drive the gate briskly. This drives the gate with a bit more than the maximum 20V, but probably still okay. To be conservative, a voltage regulator eg. LM7812 could be used to reduce it to 12V or so.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTTTuD.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Good catch showing the local bypass capacitor -- to emphasize: the MOSFET, catch diode and capacitor should be co-located, minimal loop length between them. | Gate voltage can also be limited by putting a resistor in series with Q1; which, the NPN emitter follower might not be necessary otherwise, but it will be a little handy with this extra resistance.